# Executing multiple rename commands with find

Tags: find

Want to use the find command with a number of rename commands. How can I do it.

This is the sequence I want to execute with the `find` command

```
rename "s/ /-/g" * ; rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' * ; rename 's/[.]-/-/g' * ; rename 's/--/-/g' *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need separate `rename`'s here. The first `argument` to rename can be any `perl` code that does the modifications you want on the file path (as stored in `$_`), you don't have to use `s/pattern/replacement/flags` let alone only one of them.

Here, you could just do:

```
find . -depth -exec rename -n -d '
  $_ = lc $_; # lowercase
  s/[ .-]*[ -]+/-/g' {} +
```

Or if your `rename` doesn't support `-d`:

```
find . -depth -mindepth 1 -exec rename -n '
  my ($dirname, $basename) = m{(.*)/(.*)}s;
  $basename = lc $basename; # lowercase
  $basename =~ s/[ .-]*[ -]+/-/g;
  $_ = "$dirname/$basename"' {} +
```

here turning all `<0-or-more-spaces-or-dot-or-dash><1-or-more-spaces-or-dash>` to a single dash, but you could do all your `s/.../.../`s instead, separated with `;`s:

```
find . -depth -exec rename -n -d '
  s/ /-/g;
  y/A-Z/a-z/;
  s/[.]-/-/g;
  s/--/-/g' {} +
```

In any case, you want to make sure the substitutions are only applied to the basename (hence the `-d`) and that leaves are renamed before the branches they're on (hence the `-depth`).

(`-n`s above are for dry-run).